# In the following jQuery piece of code, how can I select from the multiSelect

Tags: jquery, multi-select

I am trying to select elements from multiSelect jQuery plugin

1st try:

```
$("#id").multiSelect('select', ['1', '8', '14'])
```

2nd try:

```
let selectedOptions = ['1', '8', '14'];

$.each(selectedOptions, function (i, v) {
    var optionVal = selectedOptions[i];
    $("#SelectedCities").find("optgroup option[value=" + optionVal + "]").prop("selected", "selected");
})

$("#SelectedCities").multiSelect("refresh");
```

But it didn't work.
any ideas?

this is how i initializing it iam using after init callback

`

```
     callbacks: function () {
                    $sel.multiSelect("destroy").multiSelect({
                        afterInit: function () {
                            fetch(`/Area/controller/GetCitys`).then(result => {
                                return result.json();
                            })
                            .then(data => {
                                let Area = data.Area
                                let Cities = data.Cities
                                if (Area.length > 0 && Cities.length > 0) {
                                    $.each(Area, function (i, v) {
                                        html += `<optgroup class="font-weight-bold" label=${v.Text}>`
                                        $.each(Cities, function (ind, val) {
                                            if (v.Value == val.Parent) {
                                                html += `<option value="${val.Value}">${val.Text}</option>`;
                                            }
                                        })
                                        html += "</optgroup>";
                                    })
                                    //       console.log(html)
                                    $sel.append(html);
                                    $sel.multiSelect("destroy").multiSelect("refresh").multiSelect({ selectableOptgroup: true });
                                }
                                else {
                                    $sel.empty().append('<option selected="selected" value="0">empty<option>');
                                }
                            })
                                .catch(error => console.log(error));
                        }
                    })
                },
`
```

Comment: Please post the HTML - it will help if we can see what `#id` looks like.

Comment: <select multiple="multiple" class="multi-select" id="id" name="id[]"></select>

Comment: So there are no `<option>` elements for your `<select>`?

Comment: i updated the post with how i created it

Comment: Thanks for updating, but please format the code properly: paste in your JavaScript, *select* it, then click on the "Code Sample" button - that will ensure it's all wrapped in a `<pre>` tag.

Comment: is this ok ???? iam trying my best i new here

Comment: Thanks again - we're definitely getting closer. So you're setting the `value` attribute via `value="${val.Value}"` - are these definitely numbers, like in your `selectedOptions` variable? What would be helpful is if you could post the *rendered* HTML once your callback has finished. You can do this by right-clicking on the `<select>`, choosing "Inspect Element", then copying/pasting the HTML into your question.